# EM18 module + Raspberrypi

Tags: rfid

I am using EM18 RFID module. When I connect Module alone to 12v supply it works great but when I connect raspberrypi also to the same 12v supply to power (12v to 5v using buck converter) then EM18 module dosent work as good as it worked when connected alone to the supply(range decreases, read in every attempt is not guaranteed). 
What could be the possible issue ?

And please don't tell me to repost this question on Raspberrypi stack exchange :)

Comment: It can be many things, but first I would check that you are not exceeding the maximum supply current of the supply.

Comment: Can you post the connection diagram for both working and non working solution.. also the details about the 12 V supply and the 6 V buck

Comment: Eugene, I am using supply with enough current (3 Amps).
Umar connection diagram is very common. Just connected both raspberrypi(powered by boost converter which at the end connected to supply) and EM18 module in parallel.